# Howto install the free Mac OS X (10.9 Mavericks) on a computer running Windows?

Tags: macos

AFAIK 10.9 Mavericks is a free Mac App Store download, but how can I get it onto a computer that isn't running an earlier version of Mac OS X? Or is it another type of free that Apple means ;-)

Comment: Since I posted in the wrong SE site, should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is free. But you have to own a Mac if you want to use it. That's a part of the CGU and it's illegal to do it in another way.

Furthermore, your question belong to the [Apple SE forums](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thx for pointing me to the right SE site. I searched for Mac on the SE main site, but the Apple site didn't come up.

Comment: I of course found an answer to question on the Apple SE forum - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107324 In my ears 10.9 Mavericks is a free upgrade, it's not free. Anyway, I have probably just misread the tech news.

Comment: @hansfn which is implicit if you own a Mac :)